# Why @selector can call a method which is declared in an implementation file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I have declared (between @interface and @end) and implemented a method in the .m file of Class A. For instance:

```
- (void)zoneChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"The system time zone has changed!");
}
```

And in Class B, I want to send `zoneChange` message to a observer when the system zone is changed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:anObserver
                                         selector:@selector(zoneChange:)
                                             name:NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

The code above works. When user changes the time zone on Mac, `zoneChange` method get called. However, the compiler gives me  a warning about the @selector: **Undeclared selector "zoneChange:"**. What confused me is that since`zoneChange` is a private method, why can it been seen by the @selector in Class B beyond the Class A? Anyone can explain it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private methods are just that: private. They still exist, they're just kept secret from the outside world. There's nothing built in to Objective-C to check where a method is being called from and complain at runtime; that compile-time warning about an undeclared selector is exactly the failure of Class B to see the method that you expect!

Comment: Does that mean if the compiler doesn't complain, outside world can call the private method?

Comment: @WangYudong: exactly. You can get around your current warning, even, by declaring the method in a class extension before using `@selector`.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of Objective-C, when you write `[receiver zoneChange:note]`, you are actually *sending a message* (`zoneChanged:`) to the receiving object `receiver`, rather then making a function call directly. Although eventually there are some C-functions called, the Objective-C messages are still very different from the traditional C functions - I think that's why you are confused.

C functions are "static." The process of calling a C function is in fact just jumping to some point and executing some code, which is determined at compile time. However, *messages* are processed at run-time. Objective-C is a dynamic language, which means you can add methods or even classes at run time. As a result, there is no way to determine whether a class implements (or *responds*) to one particular selector at compile-time. Case in point, some accessors of `NSManagedObject` are added at run time when called. So despite the warning, actually you can send any message to any object (including `nil`) using `performSelector` without getting a compilation error.